# Replace values of a column from another column with the same month and year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame that looks like this

```
df:
    date    close open
01/01/2012   5      5
01/02/2012   5      5
01/31/2012   5      5
02/29/2012   5      5
03/02/2012   5      5
10/15/2012   5      5
10/21/2012   5      5
11/21/2012   5      5
...........   .     .
```

and have a series which contains the deadline dates for each month and their values of close on that day

```
deadlines       close
01/30/2012       10
02/25/2012       20
10/20/2012       10
11/20/2012       20
```

Based from my dataframe, the trades that did not close on the deadline are

```
01/31/2012
02/29/2012
10/21/2012 
11/21/2012
```

I want to change the values of the close that falls on these dates to values assigned on the day of the deadlines. Therefore, I want my df to look like this

```
df:
    date    close open
01/01/2012   5      5
01/02/2012   5      5
01/31/2012   10     5
02/29/2012   20     5
03/02/2012   5      5
10/15/2012   5      5
10/21/2012   10     5
11/21/2012   20     5
...........   .     .
```

can someone help me?

Comment: See my answer below. You edited the question after my post. See edited answer

Comment: for that, I will only change the dates that goes beyond the deadline dates

Comment: See my latest edits. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

In lieu of your comment. Can add

**Dataframes used**

[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
#Coerce the dates to datetime
deadline['date']=pd.to_datetime(deadline['date'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#Merge to the nearest key to get missed datetlines. Note the direction must be backward
df3=pd.merge_asof(df, deadline,left_on="date", right_on="date", direction="backward",tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5D'), suffixes=('_left', '')).dropna()
df3.drop(columns=['close_left'], inplace=True)
#Combine dataframes
df4 = (df3.set_index('date').combine_first(df.set_index('date')).reset_index())
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I think I did not clarify more my question. Is there any method that im directly dealing with the dates and not just their position on the dataframe? For instance ```df.loc[df.date < deadline.dates]```

Comment: The same method would still apply even if you were matching using date objects.

Comment: It does not work for me since the deadline dates is different from df.date

Comment: it returns empty dataframe:(

Comment: How are your dates different from the ones you gave in this question? Because they are certainly working for me.Happy to withdraw my answer to allow others have a try

Comment: It looks like that. I have dates that does not go beyond the deadline dates and dates that goes beyond the deadline dates. For each months of the dates I have has a corresponding deadline dates

Comment: Could you please re-frame your question to say that, include a variety of dates and expected outcomes so that we can see what you really want. From the explanation I am not clear on what you would like done.

Comment: done!. Please ask more question if it still not clear